# 'Unable to download JS bundle' error on Android 4

Tags: react-native

I'm working on React Native on Windows and I have a problem on my phone (Android 4.1.2).

I am following the quick start tutorial but, i have a problem in the guide "Running on Device". (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content)
I can't use adb reverse because I've Android 4.1 and not Android 5.0+. If I try, I have an error: closed.

My question is about the second part : Configure device to connect to the dev server via Wi-Fi.
When I go to "developer options", I don't understand how I can write my machine's IP address. I can access to my development server with my phone's browser but, in my app, I have just red page with the error "Unable to dowload JS bundle".

How can I try to resolve this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't gone through these steps myself for Android, but have for iOS and assume it's basically the same concept. It's unclear to me whether you were able to successfully get through all these steps... were you?

## Configure device to connect to the dev server via Wi-Fi

1. Open rage shake menu (shake the device) or run `adb shell input keyevent 82`
2. Go to `Dev Settings`
3. Go to `Debug server host for device`
4. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the packager (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081) and `Reload JS`. On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network.

I suspect that you're getting hung up on step 4, where you need to enter the IP address of your windows machine plus port as the `debug server host for device`. This is where you point to the JSBundle. On iOS, we update the AppDelegate.m file with the development machine's IP address. I'll have to play with Android more to get more familiar with your situation.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is on step 3.

I haven't this "Debug server host for device" on the dev settings. So, I don't know where I can enter the IP address.

Comment: Ok, so I've pretty much been working on this all day. I needed to setup my Android environment eventually anyway, so figured I might as well do it now and try and be helpful at the same time. I've not yet gotten this working, but here's what I think I've learned which may help you.

# Try connecting USB Debugging first...

Answer (score 3):

i think the most important to fix "unable to download js bundle" is that we have to start local server first to be able to load js bundle

1. run react-native run-android (your app will load with a red screen, etc on this step)
2. run react-native start (to start local server)
3. On device, shake to get in developer menu
4. Click on Reload JS and it works:)

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/RunningOnDeviceAndroid.md#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi) to make it clearer:

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device.
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. We'll fix this in the following steps.
4. Open the Developer menu by **shaking the device** or running `adb shell input keyevent 82` from the command line.
5. Go to **Dev Settings**.
6. Go to **Debug server host for device**.
7. Type in **your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server** (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). **On Mac**, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. **On Windows**, open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).
8. Go back to the Developer menu and select **Reload JS**.

Comment: after doing this the app crashes on my phone when i re open it. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not having any luck connecting via USB either. Martin, if you want to spend some time with me figuring this out, I'd be happy to help update the documents once I understand what I'm doing wrong. Let me know here or on twitter (@geirmanc)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've pretty much been working on this all day. I needed to setup my Android environment eventually anyway, so figured I might as well do it now and try and be helpful at the same time. I've not yet gotten this working, but here's how I think it should work...

1. Connect your device via USB
2. Be sure to [enable USB debugging on your device](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+Enable+USB+debugging)
3. make sure there's no emulator running and from the terminal run
   `react-native run-android` this should load the app to your phone.
4. with your app running, run the `adb shell input keyevent 82`, which should open the Dev Settings menu
5. Dev Settings > Debug server host for device
6. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the packager (e.g.
   10.0.1.1:8081) and `Reload JS`

I personally can't get past step 3 above and get the RSoD (red screen of death), so I'm trying to figure that out. I'm posting this because you might have better luck getting past that step. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, just in case this leads someone to something... I found the [source of the error in the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?p=4&q=catalyst_jsload_error&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/62e8ddc20561a39c3c839ab9f83c95493df117c0/ReactAndroid/src/main/res/devsupport/values/strings.xml#L10

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/88655001e36315c2a8f3bebc1b33e5b0cad9d077/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/devsupport/DevSupportManager.java#L576